# list json data javascript

Tags: javascript, json

how to list this json data

```
[["Jomed","Montuno Noveno",""],["Neil Young","Southern Man","http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=kVRxdPWV3RM&feature=youtube_gdata_player"],["Rolling Stones","Sympathy For The Devil (Live)","http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=ZRXGsPBUV5g&feature=youtube_gdata_player"],["Kinks","Lola","http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=LemG0cvc4oU&feature=youtube_gdata_player"],["Grandmaster Flash","White Lines","http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=u0u_qxFEysI&feature=youtube_gdata_player"]]
```

i want the output like this

artist-song-youtubeUrl

### code :

```js
$.getJSON('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('http://www.radioactivefm.gr/live/api/last5Json.php') + '&callback=?',

    function(data){

  $('body').html(data.contents);

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

please your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $.getJSON('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('http://www.radioactivefm.gr/live/api/last5Json.php') + '&callback=?',        
        function(data) {
              $('body').html(JSON.parse(data.contents).map(function(item, index){return item[0] + "-" + item[1] + "-" + item[2]}));    
    });
```